# uploadFile from Angular4 to Symfony : POST Method

Tags: angular, symfony, post, file-upload

I would like to use an Angular4 form to send a file to Symfony via the POST method.

After some research, I came across this method:

```
upload(event): void
{
    console.log('File : ', event.target.files[0]);
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('File', event.target.files[0]);
    console.log('FormData:', formData);
    this.myService.upload(formData).subscribe((res) => 
    console.log('res : ', res))
}
```

But I already have a problem here. The formData log returns an empty object...

Return of console.log :

```
FormData: FormData {}__proto__: FormData
File : File {name: "images.jpg", lastModified: 1507624281000, lastModifiedDate: Tue Oct 10 2017 10:31:21 GMT+0200 (CEST), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 52001, …}
```

If you know another way to send a file (jpeg/png) to Symfony I'm really interested, I've been blocking it for a while...
Thank you in advance and good day/evening.

The input type File:

```
<input (change)="upload($event)" type="file" class="form-control" id="file" (ngModel)="model.file" name="file" required>
```

UPDATE:

I solved my problem.

Here's the solution:

On the Symfony side, the formData functioned correctly, you just had to add (to recover the file:)

```
$file = $request->files->get('File');
```

--' <= I feel noob...

See you soon:)

Comment: Could you put your solution into the answer below? That would make it more obvious and easy for people to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

The solution is :

On the Symfony side, the formData functioned correctly, you just had to add (to recover the file:)

```
$file = $request->files->get('File');
```

See you soon:)